# What Coordinate of image was clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, click, coordinates

I want to show an image to the user and get the pixel of image that user clicks or the coordinates of click on the image.
Actually I want to put a dot on that image at the specified coordinates and save it on the disk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to access the clicked coordinates with WinForms (since you didn't specify...):

1. Add a PictureBox to your form
2. Add a Click event handler

> ```
> private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   var mouseArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e;
>   // coordinates are now available in mouseArgs.X and mouseArgs.Y
> }
> ```

**Edit:**
And here's how to do it in WPF:

1. Add an Image to your canvas
2. Add a MouseDown event handler

> ```
> private void image1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
> {
>   var clickedPoint = e.GetPosition((Image)sender);
>   // coordinates are now available in clickedPoint.X and clickedPoint.Y
> }
> ```

**Edit:**
And for completeness, here's one way to do it in ASP.NET:

1. Add an ImageButton to your form
2. Add a Click event handler

> ```
> protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
> {
>   // coordinates are now available in e.X and e.Y
> }
> ```

Comment: What if it was zoomed in or rescaled because of window limitations?for example a 1920x1600 image is shown in a 800x600 window.

Comment: It will give you the clicked point within the `Image` control. So if the image is 1920x1611, but the Image is scaled to 800x600, and I click exactly in the bottom right corner, the coordinates will be X = 800, Y = 600

Comment: Then You are saying I have to translate the coordinates myself?

Comment: If you want to translate the real coordinates into the ones that _would_ have been clicked had the image been full size... yes. But that's not difficult. Lets say the full size image is 1920 pixels wide, and the scaled down version is only 400 pixels wide. To get the X coordinate in the full size version, when the user clicks on the scaled down version: `(1920 / 400) * e.X`

Comment: If using `Stretch="Uniform"` this becomes a bit harder.